# Constant name format in Joomla

Tags: joomla2.5

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<metadata>
        <layout title="COM_HELLOWORLD_HELLOWORLD_VIEW_DEFAULT_TITLE">
                <message>COM_HELLOWORLD_HELLOWORLD_VIEW_DEFAULT_DESC</message>
        </layout>
        <fields name="request">
                <fieldset name="request">
                        <field
                                name="id"
                                type="list"
                                label="COM_HELLOWORLD_HELLOWORLD_FIELD_GREETING_LABEL"
                                description="COM_HELLOWORLD_HELLOWORLD_FIELD_GREETING_DESC"
                                default="1"
                        >
                                <option value="1">Hello World!</option>
                                <option value="2">Good bye World!</option>
                        </field>
                </fieldset>
        </fields>
</metadata>
```

Is it necessary to call constants in its style (as i now joomla is using pattern observer) or can i simply call it like `COM_HELLOWORLD_HELLO` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The constant you are referring to is a language constant. These are used in the different language files to offer multiple languages.

The style is purely a format that has been created to ensure these language strings are easy to use.

You can therefore call constants what ever you like - no spaces obviously!